# Can my boss stop employees from going to the brewery next door?

Tags: legal

Long story short, there's a brewery opening next door to us and my boss is VERY against the idea of them serving beer in a tasting room (it's mostly a shipping and packaging facility with a small tasting room). So much in fact that he got a petition going and is asking for signatures, making a lot of phone calls and basically doing everything in his power to stop the tasting room.

This is not a tasting room where they'll be serving enormous amounts of beer and having people getting trashed from it, think of a wine tasting room, very small portions of "fancy" beer.

Now I'm a beer lover and would like to go over. Can he stop us (employees) from going next door and drinking there? After work hours of course.

Comment: Dependant on where you are I doubt he could legally stop you from going there after work, but he could make life difficult for you in other ways. Also depends on your job, if you are a pilot for instance you can lose your job if you drink outside working hours but within legally mandated limits before flying.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Purely legal questions are off topic.  The country you are in, possibly the state, and your employment contract (if any) will come in to play.  If you are in the United States, for example, and your employment is "at will", your boss would be free to fire you for any reason (or no reason) that doesn't run afoul of some anti-discrimination rule.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic, assuming that the question is "can employees be legally stopped from getting a drink there?" and that the IANAL answer is "probably not." Better question might be if there becomes an unofficial rule against going next door, how best to handle?

Comment: You did not mention what is driving your boss to take such drastic action, and doing crazy things like petitioning to close another legitimate business ? Is there a drinking problem in company, generally speaking ? Is he against alcohol consumption of any kind ? Religious fanatic ? There has to be a reason ..

Comment: Are you sure he's not opposed to the extra foot traffic in the area or maybe drunk customers instead drinking in general?

Comment: @MelBurslan No drinking issues within the company. He isn't against alcohol consumption, as he has beer every now and then. I'm not sure to be honest and it's really not my business to ask anyways, he'd just go on some rant on how it's not my business and not to worry about it etc

Comment: @JeffO I don't think so. Like I said, it's a tasting room with small portions in an industrial side of town surrounded by other businesses. And it's a microbrewery

Comment: @DJClayworth Located in California, US

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Unless he sees them enter or leave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally your boss probably cannot dictate what you do or not outside work hours.

But if you are in "at will" employment your boss would be free to fire you as commented by Justin Cave.

If he is asking you to sign a petition that is really pushing it but still probably not much you can do.  Is he using business time to try and shut down a tasting room?  Does his boss know about this?

I would kind of lay low as this is someone with power that feels strongly about this.  He can't cover the door every day.  Just slip in one day after work when the boss is not looking.

Comment: He hasn't asked us to sign it. Although I fear that may come, I'm not sure. Yes he's using the business time to do this, but he's also the owner

Comment: I would lay low and sign it.  Not fair but not likely he will get enough signatures to shut it down.

Comment: My neighbors wanted to stop a local bar from coming into the neighborhood.   I wanted a bar I could walk to.  But I went ahead and signed the petition to not cause a stir.  Then they asked be to share in a legal fund to stop the bar - that was clear NO.

Comment: Luckily, CA is not "at will."

Comment: @AmyBlankenship : I beg to differ as a California resident for the past 12 years. It is an At-Will employment state. [SEE HERE](http://business.ca.gov/StartaBusiness/AdministeringEmployees/EqualEmploymentOpportunityLaws/AtWillEmployment.aspx)

Comment: @MelBurslan it has a lot more protections than, for example, Mississippi.

Comment: Agreed but still, if a boss is after you for this reason or that, he can let you go, without citing a reason.

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?

Comment: I disagree about "laying low and signing it". Just say that you respectfully disagree and even though you may not patronize the place you feel it's not your right to tell another company how they can operate unless there's reason to believe it will be disruptive. Either your boss will leave you alone, or if he's really passionate about it, maybe he'll explain *why* he wants to shut it down.